# The WCF service which has net tcp and http bindings does not activate when calling the net tcp endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I created a WCF service with 2 end points: One has `netTcpBinding` and other `WsHttpBinding`.

I deployed the service locally to an IIS site. I then created a console application and added a service reference to the service on my local box. I then called the service method using tcp endpoint, it failed with an activation error.

Recycling the application pool and calling the service method on http endpoint worked and activated the service. After that the tcp endpoint also worked.

I want to know if there is a way that the net tcp endpoint will also activate the service.

Comment: Activation errors usually write some sort of event to the windows application and/or system event logs.  Try checking in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're configuring your service to expose a netTcpBinding endpoint, I assume you are using IIS 7x  to host it. There is a gotcha with Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) hosted services in IIS, you need to make sure that the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter (Windows Service) is running. Check this in Computer Management>Services and Applications>Services pane (Windows 2008 Server might be a slightly different path but you get the idea).

Also check the Log On tab of the Properties dialog box and ensure the log on account that it is using has at least Read & Execute permissions (it might need Full but I don't remember exactly) on the site hosting your WCF service.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you're describing a behavior that is a common issue with the netMsmqBinding. IIS will "stand-down" WCF service instances after a period of inactivity (I think the default is 20 minutes) to conserve memory and resources. After this stand-down, the MSMQ listener adapter sometimes does not "wake-up" the appropriate service on detecting a new message in a queue. Most times, this is because the account of the net.msmq listener adapter doesn't have permission to the configured queue for the service.

In your case, it seems the net.tcp listener adapter is failing to start a new service instance to handle incoming TCP requests in a similar fashion to the MSMQ issue. To troubleshoot the problem, try using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) on the server hosting the service to watch the incoming requests when the service is active and after it has become inactive long enough for IIS to stand it down. You can also use the [Resource Monitor](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/111020-resource-monitor.html) that is part of Task Manager to see which processes are using network resources when the your client calls are made. See if the net.tcp listener adapter service is receiving any network traffic.

It seems the basic issue is the net.tcp listener adapter isn't firing up a WCF service instance on receiving TCP traffic for the service endpoint. My client has many services configured for netTcpBinding but I don't recall their having this problem in the past. That makes me suspicious the configuration of the net-tcp listener adapter or the web site/web application in IIS is not quite right.

Comment: I am using IIs 75 to host my service and also verified that Net.Tcp listener adapter is running. Also ebaled net.tcp protocol in my IIS advanced settings. I am still getting avtication exception when i try to call service method from tcp endpoint. Recycling application pool in IIS and calling service method from http endpoint works and activates the service. Recycling appl pool and trying to call from tcp endpoint works without any exception. I am not sure why tcp endpoint is not activating the service.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this will help me in resolving my issue.